# Пример работы событий

Tags: yii, php, php-frameworks

Привет...Никак не разбирусь с работой событий в Yii.

Можно полный пример чтобы посмотреть и тестировать эту возможность...?

Припустим если идет вызов события $obj->onrun() я хочу вызвать метод

```
function (){echo 'onrunned';}
```

*Никто не сталкивался??*

Answer (score 1):

Хорошая [статья](http://www.elisdn.ru/blog/45/events-programming-on-yii) по событиям в Yii. Вначале автор описывает что это такое, где и как применяется. Если с этим и так все понятно, можно начинать читать с раздела "Использование событий в Yii".